# Manually update 1020 to latest version of WP8.1?

Tags: 8.1, update, nokia-lumia-1020

I've bought a Lumia 1020, and I'm not convinced my phone provider has rolled out the latest version of the 8.1 OS (is it each phone provider's choice when to do this?) It doesn't look like my previous 1020 (it failed), all the tiles look a lot bigger and cruder though I do not know the exact version number on my old phone.

Can I download and manually install an OS image? I'm using this wiki page as my reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_version_history

Comment: The tile size can be changed in the settings. Your new phone is probably using the large default tile size.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current build version going to Settings -> Info.

The only way I can think of is reinstalling the OS through the [Windows Device Recovery Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-device-recovery-tool-faq). This might allow you to install a newer build - you can see the OS Version when plugging in your phone, before you actually reinstall. My 930 would receive the GDR1 with Build 9651.14226.

You could also install the Windows 10 Insider Preview on your 1020, unfortunately this is not officially supported for your device and so you won't get any updates past the Anniversary Update.

Comment: Am I correct that WP10 is no longer going to support the 1020 so I can have a buggy preview only?

Comment: That's the current state, yes.

Comment: I'm confused. The recovery tool only talks about firmware version, not OS version. These numbers are not at all similar e.g. it says my firmware is 3051.50009.1451.1004 and my OS is 8.10.14226.359. The recovery tool says my firmware version is newer than the server version (.1424.0004) and I can't get a newer OS - I'm missing out on GDR2? Any ideas

Comment: recovery tool re installs your phone  to lumia cyan, the 1st 8.1 version. i guess, that's what you need,right?

Comment: @RamRaj I want the newest stable version of 8.1... according to wikipedia I am several versions behind!

Comment: well, i just rolled back to 8.1 previous week using this tool, i got 1st version , and then i went to updates and got the newest update of 8.1.